# Cordova app is launching mobile safari each time I navigate to a jQueryMobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

My app does the right thing and navigates to the select page each time I follow a jQuery Mobile link, but it also launches a copy of that page in Mobile Safari when I run in the iPhone Emulator.  I'm sure I'm just missing some configuration setting.

Here is my mobileinit function

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', () -> 
  $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true
)
```

And I've modified the `ExternalHosts` array in `Cordova.plist` to whitelist my app server's domain name.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.This solution works fine.

http://moduscreate.com/opening-all-urls-with-phonegaps-childbrowser-plugin/